# Getting JS values from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

So basically im some sort of likeing system on posts
I am trying to create a single JS script that will handle the likes via AJAX
So far i have done this

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {    
    $("#like").click(function(){

        var post_id = document.getElementById(this).value;

        $.ajax({
             url: 'Js_returns/status_like.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(post_id)},
             success: function(data) {
                $("#status_like_" + post_id).append(data);
             }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my "Like" button

```
<div id="like" value="', $status['postid'] ,'">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
<i id="status_like_', $status['postid'] ,'">',$status['like_count'],'</i>
</div>
```

Im kinda new to JS so please no silly comments
So here is what im aiming for

When the user clicks the button, the JS gets the div id value (Eg; 1)
Then that value is passed to the PHP file via POST method
After that, i know how to code it (im pretty good at php so you dont need to explain that part)

Btw, when using this, i get this browser error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Comment: put variables inside `<?php echo $variable;?>`

Comment: I think thats insecure :O

Comment: Your id in your code sinipit is invalid it should be something like `LikeStatus` instead those bunch of quotes and commas.

Comment: @rekire , its in a php file so those quotes and commas are nessecary for php variables

Comment: Oh my god, now I got what you are doing. Please just write here the output html or the full php line, not just the related html from your php code. However the div tag has no value attribute this might cause your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'browser error' is due to referencing the `value` on a `null`-object, because `document.getElementById()` should have an id as parameter, not a DOM element. Change that line into (but see the edit below):

```
var post_id = document.getElementById(this.id).value;
```

Or easier, using JQuery:

```
var post_id = $(this).val();
```

---

Edit: as rekire pointed out in a comment, a `div` has no `value` attribute. You could put the id in the `id` attribute and use a `class` to associate the onclick handler:

php:

```
echo '<div id="like_' . $status['postid'] . '" class="like">';
```

javascript (in the ready-function, as you currently have it):

```
$(".like").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);
    ...
```

This will get the value of the `id` attribute of the div. The `like_`-part is there so that the id will be unique in the html (using just a number can result in collisions). After getting the element's id, use `substr` to remove the `like_`-part.

Answer (score 0):

if i read your post correctly u just want the value of the #like div

```
<div id="like" value="', $status['postid'] ,'">
```

assuming a value is set, because the page is rendered server side. Since your using jquery already,this is all you need to do:

```
$("#like").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
         url: 'Js_returns/status_like.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(post_id)},
         success: function(data) {
            $("#status_like_" + post_id).append(data);
         }
    });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

This below does not work, getElementById expects a string referencing the Id,
thats why it returns Null, and u can't get a value of null

```
var post_id = document.getElementById(this).value;
```

hope this helps you...

Comment: So far this works but only for the FIRST post
When i try to like other posts, nothing happens
http://prntscr.com/858jqc

$("#like").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
         url: 'Js_returns/status_like.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {"data" : JSON.stringify(post_id)},
         success: function(data) {
            $("#status_like_" + post_id).append(data);
         }
    });
});

Comment: @Champa: that's because the div's all have the same id. See my answer, which solves that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

your following code contains , (comma) !!!! which is wrong ..

```
<div id="like" value="', $status['postid'] ,'">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
<i id="status_like_', $status['postid'] ,'">',$status['like_count'],'</i>
</div>
```

it should be as follows:

```
<div id="like" value="<?php echo $status['postid']; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <i id="status_like_'<?php echo $status['postid']; ?>'"><?php echo $status['like_count']; ?></i>
    </div>
```

as I assume you are using jQuery you can get the post id as follows:

```
var post_id = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'browser error' is due to referencing the value on a null-object, because document.getElementById() should have an id as parameter, not a DOM element. Change that line into (but see the edit below):

```
var post_id = document.getElementById(this.id).value;
Or easier, using JQuery:

var post_id = $(this).val();
```

Edit: as rekire pointed out in a comment, a div has no value attribute. You could put the id in the id attribute and use a class to associate the onclick handler:

php:

```
echo '<div id="like_' . $status['postid'] . '" class="like">';
```

javascript (in the ready-function, as you currently have it):

```
$(".like").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);
    ...
```

This will get the value of the id attribute of the div. The like_-part is there so that the id will be unique in the html (using just a number can result in collisions). After getting the element's id, use substr to remove the like_-part.

Marten Thanks very much !